# ASP.net AutoMapper Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Domain model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
AutoMapper.Initialize();
```

AutoMapper:

```
public static class AutoMapper
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        CreateModelsToViewModels();
        CreateViewModelsToModels();
    }

    private static void CreateModelsToViewModels()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => x.CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>().ReverseMap());

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }

    private static void CreateViewModelsToModels()
    {

    }
}
```

Configuration is valid.

```
public ActionResult Index(string category)
{
    Test t = _Context.test.First(x => x.Id == 1);
    var test = Mapper.Map<Test, TestViewModel>(t); //error here
}
```

Only data is one row with an Id of 1. Even this simple test keeps throwing me the error `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`.
What could be the problem?

Edit: Changed `Mapper.Initialize(x => x.CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>().ReverseMap());` to `Mapper.Initialize(x => x.CreateMap<Test, TestViewModel>());` and still same error

Comment: Not at my computer, so I can't verify, but my guess is that you are initializing AutoMapper twice (ModelToVm and VmToModel), thus overwriting one of the initializations when you call a second time?

Comment: @Sam I have edited post, still getting error. Also I have commented out all my other code, so it is only initializing automapper once for them models.

Comment: `ReverseMap()` Creates a map both ways. so I deleted my wrong answer

Comment: Where in 'Global.asax.cs' are you calling 'Automapper.Initialize()'? Are you 100% certain that the method is being called?

Comment: @Will At the end of Application_Start() after the other methods. Yes it is being called, I set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had forgotten to update the database (Using database migration) after creating these test classes to map.

For anyone else having this problem, make sure you use `update-database` in package manager console if your using database migrations, otherwise you get this confusing error:

> AutoMapper Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.